# assetics and filters part 2 : the star character

Tags: symfony, assetic

I have 2 css files in `myBundle/Resources/public/css` and 1 css file in `myBundle/Resources/public/JQMenu/css`

In my template I call those css that way :

```
{% stylesheets 
    '@myBundle/Resources/public/css/*'
    '@myBundle/Resources/public/JQMenu/css/*'
    filter='cssembed'
%}
```

So I imagined that the star character meant : all of the css.

But at the end only 2 css are loaded and the second one has the name of the `JQMenu` ones but the content of the second css in `public/css` ... strange no ?

Comment: Is this the complete code? What if you remove the `filter`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried specifying an output file? A more complete code example based on your original question:

```
{% stylesheets output='css/combined.css'
    '@myBundle/Resources/public/css/*'
    '@myBundle/Resources/public/JQMenu/css/*'
    filter='cssembed'
%}
<link href="{{ asset_url }}" rel="stylesheet" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

This will dump the combined output in your web/css folder, after running the usual commands:

```
php app/console cache:clear
php app/console assetic:dump
```

As you're dumping assets in dev mode (by default) you should see the combined css file and its component parts (example filenames):

```
combined.css
combined_main_1.css
combined_other_2.css
combined_jqmenu_3.css
```

This output plus the manual inspection of the combined.css file should quickly tell us if all your CSS files are now being included correctly.